# Dictionary from a text file in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

#### Problem:

I have a txt file with this format:

```
Intestinal infectious diseases (001-003)  
001 Cholera  
002 Fever  
003 Salmonella   
Zoonotic bacterial diseases (020-022)  
020 Plague  
021 Tularemia  
022 Anthrax  
External Cause Status (E000)  
E000 External cause status  
Activity (E001-E002)  
E001 Activities involving x and y  
E002 Other activities
```

where each line that begins with the 3-integer code/E+3-integer code/V+3-integer code is a value for the preceding header, which are the keys for my dictionary. In other questions I've seen, the use of columns or colons can be used to parse each line to make a key/value pair, but the format of my txt file doesn't allow me to do that.

Is the a way to make a txt file like this into a dictionary where the keys are the group names and the values are the code+disease names?

I also need to parse the code and disease names into a second dictionary, so I end up with a dictionary that contains the group names as keys, with the values being a second dictionary with the codes as keys and the disease names as values.

#### Script:

```
def process_file(filename):
    myDict={}
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        for line in f:
            if line[0] is not int:
                if line.startswith("E"):
                    if line[1] is int:
                        line = dictionary1_values
                    else:
                        break
                else:
                    line = dictionary1_key
            myDict[dictionary1_key].append[line]
```

Desired output format is:
`{"Intestinal infectious diseases (001-003)": {"001": "Cholera", "002": "Fever", "003": "Salmonella"}, "Zoonotic bacterial diseases (020-022)": {"020": "Plague", "021": "Tularemia", "022": "Anthrax"}, "External Cause Status (E000)": {"E000": "External cause status"}, "Activity (E001-E002)": {"E001": "Activities involving x and y", "E002": "Other activities"}}`

Comment: Please include the sample data as well instead of images.

Comment: `line[0] is not int` is not going to work. You may require `isinstance(line[0], int)`. And depending on the `file`, the whole code is not going to work. Please paste a sample data as @HenryYik asked

Comment: Seems tricky, since both a header and a code-plus-disease can start with the letter "E". How can we tell that "External Cause Status (E000)" is supposed to be a header, for example? We're going to need a more sophisticated rule than "starts with digit or E". I wonder if "headers always end with parentheses, and code+disease names never end with parentheses" would work? Or are there also code+diseases with parens? Edit: no, that won't work, because of "Other food poisoning (bacterial)"

Comment: You are definitely on right track. `line` is a string. So you need to split line to access it as `line[0]`. Again line.split()[0] is again string. Do something like `isdecimal(line.split()[0])`

Comment: You should correct your indenting - the my_dict = {} should be indented under the function def and it should be returned to the calling statement.

Comment: I still do not understand exactly how to look at the output of your function. Draw or write how you want it to look exactly like the output of the function (an example of some for the `myDict` dictionary output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def process_file(filename):
    myDict = {}
    rootkey = None
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    for line in f:
        if line[1:3].isdigit():           # if the second and third character from the checked string (line) is the ASCII Code in range 0x30..0x39 ("0".."9"), i.e.: str.isdigit()
            subkey, data = line.rstrip().split(" ",1)     # split into two parts... the first one is the number with or without "E" at begin
            myDict[rootkey][subkey] = data
        else:
            rootkey = line.rstrip()       # str.rstrip() is used to delete newlines (or another so called "empty spaces")
            myDict[rootkey] = {}          # prepare a new empty rootkey into your myDict
    f.close()
    return myDict
```

Testing in Python console:

```
>>> d = process_file('/tmp/file.txt')
>>>
>>> d['Intestinal infectious diseases (001-003)']
{'003': 'Salmonella', '002': 'Fever', '001': 'Cholera'}
>>> d['Intestinal infectious diseases (001-003)']['002']
'Fever'
>>> d['Activity (E001-E002)']
{'E001': 'Activities involving x and y', 'E002': 'Other activities'}
>>> d['Activity (E001-E002)']['E001']
'Activities involving x and y'
>>>
>>> d
{'Activity (E001-E002)': {'E001': 'Activities involving x and y', 'E002': 'Other activities'}, 'External Cause Status (E000)': {'E000': 'External cause status'}, 'Intestinal infectious diseases (001-003)': {'003': 'Salmonella', '002': 'Fever', '001': 'Cholera'}, 'Zoonotic bacterial diseases (020-022)': {'021': 'Tularemia', '020': 'Plague', '022': 'Anthrax'}}
```

**Warning:** First one line in the file must be just a "rootkey" ! Not "subkey" or data ! Otherwise cause may to be the raise error :-)

**A note:** Maybe you should remove the first "E" character. Or can not it be done? Do you need to leave this "E" character somewhere?

Comment: Thanks - I added an edit to provide the desired output. The 7th line of this code is returning a KeyError for me; any idea why?

Comment: Done .-). I have modified the source code as specified by you.

Comment: Thank you! The E can't be removed, I assume to make the problem trickier. Is there a way to modify the code so that the output is a dictionary of dictionaries as formatted above (i.e. in the { x:{y z}} format)?

Comment: The output format is already a dictionary data type in the another dictionary data: `{ 'rootkey1': {'subkeyA': 'dataA', 'subkeyB': 'dataB'}, 'rootkey2': {'subkeyX': 'dataX', 'subkeyY': 'dataY'} }`. And where is the error? My code works without error. Please, copy and paste the error message. Maybe your input data for processing are different from what you wrote at the beginning. This could be the cause of the error. But I do not know your input data. You must show all your data :-).

Answer (score 0):

try using regular expressions to determine if it is a header or a disease

```py
import re
mydict = {}
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    header = None
    for line in f:
        match_desease = re.match(r"(E?\d\d\d) (.*)", line)
        if not match_desease:
            header = line
        else:
            code = match_desease.group(1)
            desease = match_desease.group(2)
            mydict[header][code] = desease
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use regular expressions to help you characterize and parse the two types of lines you might encounter in this file:

```
import re
header_re = re.compile(r'([\w\s]+) \(([\w\s\-]+)\)')
entry_re = re.compile(r'([EV]?\d{3}) (.+)')
```

This allows you to very easily check which type of line you're encountering, and break it apart as desired:

```
# Check if a line is a header:
header = header_re.match(line)
if header:
    header_name, header_codes = header.groups()  # e.g. ('Intestinal infectious diseases', '001-009')
    # Do whatever you need to do when you encounter a new group
    # ...
else:
    entry = entry_re.match(line)
    # If the line wasn't a header, it ought to be an entry,
    # otherwise we've encountered something we didn't expect
    assert entry is not None
    entry_number, entry_name = entry.groups()  # e.g. ('001', 'Cholera')
    # Do whatever you need to do when you encounter an entry in a group
    # ...
```

Using that to re-work your function, we could write the following:

```
import re

def process_file(filename):
    header_re = re.compile(r'([\w\s]+) \(([\w\s\-]+)\)')
    entry_re = re.compile(r'([EV]?\d{3}) (.+)')

    all_groups = {}
    current_group = None

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            # Check if a line is a header:
            header = header_re.match(line)
            if header:
                current_group = {}
                all_groups[header.group(0)] = current_group
            else:
                entry = entry_re.match(line)
                # If the line wasn't a header, it ought to be an entry,
                # otherwise we've encountered something we didn't expect
                assert entry is not None
                entry_number, entry_name = entry.groups()  # e.g. ('001', 'Cholera')

                current_group[entry_number] = entry_name

    return all_groups
```